# Monads for Control Flow - Sequence, Selection and Iteration

Tags: scala, haskell, clojure, monads, control-flow

I can see how you'd use a Monad is Haskell for IO - to create a container around the computation for this operation. It makes sense that you can use Monads to 'plug computations together' - as you would compose functions for a dataflow operation.

What I'm only just grokking is that you can use Monads for Control Flow. Now I understand Control flow to be about Sequence, Selection and Iteration. Now I'm comfortable with higher order functions like map, foldl, filter and zipwith/mapcat to perform operations on lists.

My question is - can I do sequence, selection and iteration with monads in order to achieve control flow? 
(Happy for an answer in Haskell, Scala or Clojure)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For sequencing in Haskell, you have the functions `>>=` and `sequence`:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

The `>>=` or bind function takes a monadic action, extracts the value from it and feeds it into a function that returns a new monadic action.  The `sequence` function takes a list of monadic actions of the same type and executes all of them, aggregating their results and wrapping it as a single action.

For iteration you have `mapM` and `forM` (`forM = flip mapM`)

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

The `mapM` and `forM` functions are for applying a function that returns an action to each element in a list, aggregating the results as a single action.

For selection, I assume you mean conditionals, which are implemented in Haskell as just if-the-else expressions.  They can be used directly in monadic expressions the same as they can be used in pure expressions.  However, you can also use certain monads for performing choices or at least handling errors.  The easiest to grok is the `Maybe` monad:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a

instance Monad Maybe where
    return a = Just a
    (Just a) >>= f = f a
    Nothing  >>= f = Nothing
```

It has a very simple implementation.  Essentially, if you try to sequence a `Nothing` into anything else, it will return `Nothing` every time.  This gives you the notion of short-circuited failure:

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
-- Looks up a value in a key-value association list

myFunc :: Int -> [(String, Int)] -> Maybe Int
myFunc mult assocList = do
    i <- lookup "foo" assocList
    j <- lookup "bar" assocList
    return $ i * mult + j
```

Here, if the lookup for `"foo"` fails, the `myFunc` immediately returns `Nothing`.  Similarly if the lookup for `"bar"` fails, `myFunc` immediately returns `Nothing`.  It's only when both lookups succeed does `myFunc` do any computation.  This provides a sort of "error handling".  There's a similar monad `Either a`

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b

instance Monad (Either a) where
    return a = Right a
    (Right a) >>= f = f a
    (Left a)  >>= f = Left a
```

that works very much the same, except the "failure" value can carry some context, such as a string error message or the state of the computation at the point of failure.

Comment: Does `>>=` really guarantee sequencing or is that just the behaviour of the most common monads?

Comment: @kqr It does not guarantee sequencing of evaluation, if that is what you are asking.  The reason why is because by the order of evaluation depends on the definition of `(>>=)`, and not all implementations of `(>>=)` evaluate the first argument before the second one.

Comment: @kqr It does not guarantee sequencing, but it is the function that allows us to use `do` notation, which is what I interpreted the question as asking.  Since bind essentially defines the (implied) semicolon for each action in a do-statement, it gives us a way to define an aspect of control flow for a particular block of code.